# How to access an android app from remote server

Tags: android, remote-access

I have used some android apps to track lost phone which are accessed from web in order to track and do some operations on it(wipe all data, play loud ring etc.)

But i have no idea how they get access to the phone's app from web..

If i search i will get only list of some existing apps but no info about how to build that.

I want to know how can we trigger some activities of our app.

Please help me by suggesting any tricks or tutorials or posts..

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you build an app like that when Google is building a service build into the OS?

Comment: its not for finding lost mobile.
I want to know how can i send some simple notifications to my phone(App) from my web interface.

Comment: Try GCM : http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: In that case you either try GCM from Google or take one of the other options (xtify, parse, pushlet, urban airship, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. First you have to implement GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) in your project and then your app must have the device administration rights to perform wipe all datas and to lock your device.

GCM -  is a service that allows you to send data from your server to your users' Android-powered device. You have to perform the operation when your device receives corresponding message from server.

[GCM](http://androidcoders.wordpress.com/2012/11/17/how-to-implement-google-cloud-messaging/)  Refer this link it will help you to implement GCM.

Comment: Thank you. I will go through your link.